# bpy python - run in background or remotely?

Tags: python

How do I make this run without freezing the blender UI while it runs?

```py
import time

time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: I feel like the title of the question and the body of the question are asking two different things ?

Answer (score 2):

As shown here:

[Application Timers (bpy.app.timers) — Blender Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html)

Blender have its own timer:

```py
import bpy

def in_5_seconds():
    print("Hello World")

bpy.app.timers.register(in_5_seconds, first_interval=5)
```

Comment: not helpful, the sleep is just to simulate a running process, meaning  python is doing actively  doing something, and while it does the UI is frozen.  I am not looking to delay the start of python doing something like saying hello world